# Is it possible to automated upload an archive as static website to Github Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-api, github-pages

I'm thinking of hosting a new (static) website on Github Pages.
However the contents of this site will be re-generated on a daily basis by a automated process. It might contain > 2000 pages.

1) is there a way to automated (via api) upload a zip/tar to Github Pages with the contents of the newly generated website?
2) can GitHub Pages process a Jekyll with say +/- 2000 pages?

I've looked into the Github Contents api but could not find to upload archive. Only a single files; problem is I need the while bunch of files to be uploaded in 1 commit to be processed by the Github Pages Jejyll generator.

Comment: Who can explain this downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using git is far more efficient than sending an archive of all site's pages.

Git will only push changes made to your files it's way lighter.

Github will have no problem to processing 2000+ pages. The only limit is the 1Go size for your repository ([see here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/)).

Comment: Thx David, so you suggest to bundle eg JGit with my application to interact with Github Pages? Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: For me it's the better way. Local Jekyll -> git -> Github -> Go !

Comment: An give us an url when the site is online.